# how to replace "&" to &amp; in php

Tags: php, string

I am using this code to replace `&` to `&amp;`.

```
$arr = array();
$arr['oassade'] = 'one&1';
$arr['asdas'] = 'tw&o2';
$arr['asdsads'] = '&three123';
$columns = array($arr);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
     $arr[$key]  = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
}
print_r($arr);
```

It is not replacing, but when I change

```
$arr[$key]  = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
```

to

```
$arr[$key]  = str_replace("&", "1", $value);
```

It is replacing `&` with `1`.
What should I do?
Thanks....

Comment: It _is_ replacing. Check the source code in your browser.

Comment: your code works: http://codepad.org/gX7ww7Yp - stop viewing the result in a browser ;)

Comment: It is replacing it. Its just that your browser is displaying "&amp;" as the ampersand "&" so it appears that it's not changing.

Comment: yes it is replacing but you can not see this on web page you have to check source code, If you have firebug check with that

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `htmlspecialchars()` instead, this should encode the ampersands for you so that you don't have to worry about it.

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

> This code is working but maybe you can't see it in browser